# Finding the latest entry of an id using another table as reference

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I would like to get the latest entry of each specific id. The first table has all the ids and the other table has all the actions. Here is the sample

table one (where all ids are stored)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha |
| 2 | beta |

table two (where all actions are stored)

| id | date | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jan 1 | buy |
| 1 | jan 2 | sell |
| 2 | jan 2 | sell |
| 2 | jan 3 | buy |

the desired result is this

| id | date | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jan 2 | sell |
| 2 | jan 3 | buy |

how can i do this?

Comment: What RDBMS?  DBeaver is just  JDBC query tool.

Comment: Most RDBMS support windowing functions, search for the term top-n per group

Comment: i'm using DBeaver. Pardon me, I just started learning SQL. =(

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```sql
select 
    t2.*
from table_two t2 
inner join  
(
select 
    id,
    max(date) as max_date
from table_2
group by id
) d on d.id = t2.id and d.max_date = t2.date
```

You first get the id and max(date) from table two by grouping by the ID col.
Then you inner join that derived table back to table 2 using id and date in the join condition.

You could also restructure this to use a with clause if your DB allows it

```sql
with stage as (
select 
    id,
    max(date) as max_date
from table_2    
group by id
)
select 
 t2.*
from table_two t2 
inner join stage s on s.id = t2.id and s.max_date = t2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.date, t2.event
FROM table_two t2
WHERE t2.date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM table_two
    WHERE id = t2.id
)
ORDER BY t2.id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/A5B7gFIO